# Use a RegEx in PHP to find and save multiple occurences in a string

Tags: php, regex

I got this string:

`if(conditionA==valueA-AND-conditionB==valueB-OR-conditionC==valueC)`

The String can contain indefinite occurences of conditions.

and I want an array that contains:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(...) "conditionA==valueA"
  [1]=>
  string(...) "conditionB==valueB"
  [2]=>
  string(...) "conditionC==valueC"
}
```

I am currently using this pattern:

```
preg_match("/^if\((.+)-(.+)\)/U", $current_step_data_exploded[0], $if_statements);
```

Also, I need the "ANDs" and "ORs" so I can further check the statements.
My RegEex doesn't deliver. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "if(conditionA==valueA-AND-conditionB==valueB-OR-conditionC==valueC)";
$match = preg_match('/^if\((.+)\)$/', $string, $if);
if ($match) {
  $conditions = preg_split('/\-(AND|OR)\-/', $if[1], -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  print_r($conditions);
} else {
  echo "no matches.";
}
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => conditionA==valueA
    [1] => AND
    [2] => conditionB==valueB
    [3] => OR
    [4] => conditionC==valueC
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor and a capture group:

```
(?:\bif\((?=[^()]*\))|\G(?!^))(.*?==.*?)(?:-(?:AND|OR)-|\)$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bif\((?=[^()]*\)` Match `if(` and assert a closing `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(.*?==.*?)`
- `(?:-(?:AND|OR)-|\)$) Match one of` -AND- -OR-`or`)` and the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dsXlnt/1) | [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/L8FuW)

**Example**

```
$re = '/(?:\bif\((?=[^()]*\))|\G(?!^))(.*?==.*?)(?:-(?:AND|OR)-|\)$)/';
$str = 'if(conditionA==valueA-AND-conditionB==valueB-OR-conditionC==valueC)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => conditionA==valueA
    [1] => conditionB==valueB
    [2] => conditionC==valueC
)
```